# Fatal error when closing device with aclCloseDevice

Tags: java, lwjgl, openal

I have implemented sounds to my application using OpenAL. Seemingly it is working fine until I close the application and trying to clean up every sound related object. Basically I have a cleanup method looks like this:

```
public void cleanup(){
    //looping through sources and deleting them like this:
    alSourceStop(id);
    alDeleteSources(id);

    //ids of sources and buffers are not the same they are in different classes 

    //looping through buffers and deleting them like this:
    alDeleteBuffers(id);

    //destroying context
    alcDestroyContext(context);

    //closing device
    alcCloseDevice(device);
}
```

When I comment `alcCloseDevice` out I get a message like:

`AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed`

If I leave it in its place:

`A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment ... Failed to write core dump ...` and so on

I'm using LWJGL 3.1.0 on Windows 7 64bit os and all OpenGL and OpenAL related stuff is managed by one thread.

My set up looks like this:

```
device = alcOpenDevice((ByteBuffer)null);
ALCCapabilities caps = ALC.createCapabilities(device);
context = alcCreateContext(device, (IntBuffer)null);
alcMakeContextCurrent(context);
AL.createCapabilities(caps);
```

device and context are created without problem.

Creating buffer like this:

```
 id = alGenBuffers();

    try(STBVorbisInfo info = STBVorbisInfo.malloc()){
        ShortBuffer buffer = /*decoding ogg here without problem*/
        alBufferData(id, info.channels() == 1 ? AL_FORMAT_MONO16 : AL_FORMAT_STEREO16, buffer, info.sample_rate());
    }
```

Also set up source and listener but I don't believe that would have any impact on it, without actually creating any source and listener closing device result in error.

Comment: Which version of LWJGL are you using?

Comment: Could you add some more context, like which OS? Also how do you setup OpenAL? Is everything executed by the same thread? Because as is I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: @Vallentin I edited my question to provide more information, when I close the application this error log file is also generated, sadly it does not tell me much but I can provide it, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

- Call, parse, and output `alGetError()` after each of your openAL calls in close method. This may shed light on what is failing.
- Try dequeuing all buffers from a source before deleting your buffers. `alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, null)`;

Comment: Thank you, I'll try as soon as I can.